# Firebug - Break on Error - d is undefined

Tags: jquery, firebug

I've created a website that used to work fine. But now Firebug throws me an error while loading:

Break on Error - d is undefined (in jquery, gets loade from the google CDN)

if i turn off firebug and reload the page everything works just fine.

the site is now at http://www.optiekmeulemeester.be/test and I wanna hear if other get the same error and what can I do about it?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think this is a firebug bug, then what is the issue number?

http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/list

Comment: Ok I looked at your example page, you are running minimize jquery code, so there is no hope of finding what 'd' means. You need to run with out minimized code to debug it.

If you don't care about the error message, turn off Break on error. Either click on the [||] pause button in the Console panel or use Firebug > Firebug Icon Menu > Options > ResetAllOptions.

Comment: thanks, i don't get the error anymore thanks to resetting the option. My bad i suppose.

Answer (score 6):

We have to add a ref of /jquery.validate.min.js  in this order

```
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

works fine try this.....

Comment: This is the answer for the question surely.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you activated 'Break on all error' firebug option (it's the pause icon on the Console tab in my firebug 1.5.4) so that means that it will break on any javascript error, so now you wonder how is possible that jquery has javascript errors that makes this option to break, well, jquery and jqueryui has code like following:

```
try {
  o.ajaxOptions.success(r, s);
} catch (e) {}
```

If the success method does not exist that is a javascript error, and that is when firebug kicks in, but firebug is not able to know that error will be handled in a catch statement, and that is why you dont see any error when normally executing the code (ie. without firebug). As a side note I found [this mail](http://groups.google.com/group/firebug/browse_thread/thread/5d1dfd5e6b0de69c) about someone asking for firebug 'break on all errors' to be aware of errors inside catch statements and not break on them.

So, the solution is to deactivate the 'break on all errors' firebug option by:
 - Clicking in the Pause icon on the Console tab (this is in firebug 1.5.4)

Or as already said, the more general approach of executing Tools -> Firebug -> Options -> Reset All Firebug Options  (which will make the 'Break on all errors' go to its default off state)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting any error, but I have had that same errand message popup before. It's never a real error, my guess is it's a bug in firebug. Oh the irony.

Comment: very annoying :) i thought it was a bug too but its for weeks now that i'm getting it and really works on my nerves

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using a breakpoint inside of an ajax call, without stop it before to do the call, try using 2 breakpoints, 1 inside, and 1 BEFORE to use the ajax call, and in that way it will work.

It's a firebug bug.

Comment: Actually i haven't set any breakpoints. You mean the red dot before the line of code so it will interrupt there?? None set here.