# why is my javascript throw not working in Firebug?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, console, firebug

I'm trying to debug an application and am struggling to display my thrown errors in Firebug.

if I have something like this:

```
if (!jQuery.fn.drag){
  console.log("found an error");
  throw new Error("file xyz has not loaded");
}
```

**Question:**
Why is it, that the console fires, because there is an error, but my custom `throw` does not report anything in Firebug?

Thanks

Comment: Don't you get an error before that, something like `Jquery is undefined`? Did you manually alias `jQuery` to `Jquery`?

Comment: sorry. Typo. It should be jQuery.

Comment: What's the error that fires?

Comment: It throws nothing, the `console.log` shows, implying there is an error, but the `throw` does not show,

Comment: Please post your code _verbatim_, by copy/paste. How are we to know now that there are no further "typos" in your post?

Comment: Sure you are not just filtering the console?

Comment: @Stefan: nope. Checked that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: need a little, 2 PCs

Comment: Do you have a `catch` somewhere outside the `throw`?

Comment: @MattHuggins: let me check.

Answer (score 2):

I tried `throw new Error("error message");` and it´s [working](http://jsfiddle.net/st3fan/QQUfR/) in both Firefox and Chrome;

Use `console.log(Jquery, Jquery.fn, Jquery.fn.drag)` to debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be you accidentally activated the '**Break on all error**' firebug option, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4164651/352672) to solve it if that is your case.